# unable to upload image using cypress?

Tags: cypress, cypress-file-upload

Using this code:

```
const imagefile='aboutfirst.png';
cy.get('[name="File"]').attachFile(imagefile);
```

or

```
const imagefile='aboutfirst.png';
cy.get('#File').attachFile(imagefile);
```

I already installed the upload file path using terminal and the picture is in fixtures.

This is the HTML where I request the name:

```
<input id="File" name="File" type="file" />
```

And the response I get from cypress in both cases:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [name="File"], but never found it.
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector `cy.get('[name="File"]')` should find the `<input id="File" name="File" type="file" />` element, except if there's a shadow DOM involved.

Dev tools will show  you the **shadow root** when you inspect the element.

If so, add this line to your `cypress.json` config file

```js
{
  includeShadowDom: true
}
```